# MariaDB: Syntax error in SET variable statement

Tags: mariadb, syntax, mariadb-10.6

I have a MariaDB transaction in which for the life of me I cannot see the syntax error:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SET @config_name='test';
SET @config_version = (SELECT IFNULL(max(`Version`)+1,0) FROM `DEV`.`Config`
  WHERE `Config`.`Name` = @config_name);
INSERT INTO `DEV`.`Config`(`Name`, `Version`, `ConfigType`)
  VALUES ( @config_name, @config_version, 2 );
SET @config_id=LAST_INSERT_ID();

-- some inserts using above variables

SELECT @config_name AS ConfigName, @config_version AS ConfigVersion;
COMMIT;
```

It passed test already but for some reason it does not work on the phpMyAdmin and DBeaver interface anymore.
Anyone seeing what I don't see?

The error message is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`DEV`.`Config`.`Name` = @config_name)' at line 2

Comment: your syntax error doesn't have a `(` between `Config` and `Name`. You code here isn't what you are executing otherwise a) it would work,  or b) the error would be different.

Comment: Combine first 2 codelines to one SELECT .. INTO. Remove excess backticks. Add an alias to source table. Provide SQL code and error message which matches completely.

Comment: *The error message is .. **at line 2*** ??? Looks like your clients try to execute your code stmt-by-stmt, not as solid codeblock.

Comment: Why not use `AUTO_INCREMENT` for `version`, instead of simulating such?